# R: Datatype confusion..why does "extracting" from a data frame generate a "factor"?

Tags: r, types

I have a dataframe of a lot of variables built like this:

```
VARNAME     FILENAME
a           1.csv
b           2.csv

etc.
```

I load them into R like t his:

```
VarNamesDir<-read.table(paste(FilePathVariableNames), sep="", skip=0,header=FALSE)
```

Now, I want to access ONLY the filename of a certain variable. As already explained by you in another post I did it like this:

```
FileName<-VarNamesDir[VarNamesDir$VARNAME == VariableName, 2]
```

However, this FileName variable is now a type "factor[1]" in RStudio and if I open it it's some complex structure in which somehow all variable names are saved. Because later on I want to work through ifelse Statements like this:

```
if(FileName == "a"){
```

But then I get the error message:

```
Warning message:
In if (FileName == "a") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Why what am I doing wrong? Do I need to convert something somewhere?

Comment: Your problem is most likely not that you have a factor. However, you can avoid automatic conversion of characters to factors by adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.table`. Your real problem seems to be that you use `if` (which is not vectorized) when you should use `ifelse` (which is vectorized).

Comment: Sorry I'm still struggling with the whole R language..I've read through the Intro but still have alot uf unanswered questions. So Setting stringAsFactors to false solved the Problem. Thanks! But what is the difference between if and ifelse?! So with ifelse I can compare vectors directly and with If I cant?

Comment: The examples found in `?ifelse` should help.